# Salesforce DX vs. Einstein Discovery Stories and Models

Tags: salesforcedx, einstein-analytics, sfdx-plugin

I am currently developing an app containing Einstein Discovery elements in a scratch org.

When pulling the source code using sfdx, the story and models built are not included, as well as the Write Back Detail.

I now noticed that there is an analytics extension to sfdx (https://github.com/reidaelliott/sfdxAnalyticsQuickStart/blob/master/README.md) which should allow to create templates from apps that comprise Discovery stories, but i was not able to do this so far.

Could somebody help me and tell me if it is possible to extract the full source from the scratch org (i.e., including story, deployed model, and write-back to custom field)? If yes, how?

Thanks a lot in advance,
David